# What is this bug please? species-identification

Tags: bugs

[image]Hi, just found this bug and was curious if it was a tick or a beetle? Found on a bedroom pillow, Quebec, Canada, about 1cm long
Thank you!!

Comment: Not a tick, ticks have 8 legs. Could you give some scale and idea of where you found it? Judging by antenna it looks like a beetle

Comment: There is also a `species-identification` tag in Biology SE and [I've had great results](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A27918+%5Bspecies-identification%5D) myself. But you need to give an approximate location where in the world you are, *and also mention the approximate size!* Is this about 1 cm long? More? Less?

Answer (score 5):

This is most definitely a beetle. All [adult and nymph stage ticks have 8 legs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick#Anatomy_and_physiology), although larval stages have 6 legs. [Larval stages are tiny](https://www.cdc.gov/ticks/life_cycle_and_hosts.html) (~2 mm), so this is not a larval tick, despite the 6 legs.

So, what is it? Well, out of the [many many species of beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle#Distribution_and_diversity) (~400,000 species), there is one very large group, of which this is almost certainly a member - and that is the [weevil superfamily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil) (still 97,000 species). The distinguishing feature from other groups of beetles is the elongated rostrum or snout, which can't be seen in your photo, but creates a distinctive head shape.. Closer than that I can not work out which one it is - would need a picture of the colours and many other identifying features to work that out. There are however some common species, such as the [clover root weevil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitona_lepidus) that are fairly widespread. Some other common ones in Canada can be found [here](https://www.orkincanada.ca/pests/other/weevils/)

Comment: It reminds me of a [carrot wevil](https://entomologytoday.org/2019/04/16/new-guide-carrot-weevil-integrated-pest-management/) and I wondered if it's head was just tilted down in the top-down photo in the question, making the rostrum look shorter.